# Sweave Float environment over 2 pages

Tags: r, sweave

I have a bit of Sweave code as such:

```
<<label = Example1, echo= true>>=
//Bunch of R Code
@
```

I've tried putting it in my own float environment like so

```
\newfloat{rcode}{h!}{rcode}
\floatname{rcode}{Code Example}

\begin{rcode}[htb!]
<<label = Example1, echo= true>>=
 bunch of R code
@
\caption{First code example}
\label{CodeEx1}
\end{rcode}
```

But then the float is too big and goes on the next page. How do I get it to split over the page like it did before the environment. I've tried the `continuedfloat` package and wasn't able to get it working. I've also tried the `algorithm` package and had problems there as well.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Your specifiers of the float parameters are wrong. Please see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: You can try the [`knitr` package](http://yihui.name/knitr) instead of Sweave, with which you can use your own environment easily (e.g. https://gist.github.com/2760395) without writing `\begin{rcode}` and `\end{rcode}` repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

Floats deliberately stay together, and if necessary move to a later page to avoid leaving large spaces. Either accept this approach and use a `\label`/`\ref` to refer to your code, or don't put the code in a float and allow it to break over the page.